# Why Interlocked.Read uses Interlocked.CompareExchange internally?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, interlocked

below is the source code with my comment for Interlocked:

```
public static class Interlocked {

   // Int32 old = location;
   // if (location == comparand) location = value;
   // return old; 
   public static Int32 CompareExchange(ref Int32 location, Int32 value, Int32 comparand);

   public static long Read(ref long location)
   {
      return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref location, 0, 0);
   }

}
```

I don't understand why Read calls `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref location, 0, 0)`?

`long location` can be any number, why it is compared with 0?

Comment: Do you know what `CompareExchange` does? Because I think it'd help to begin there.

Comment: yes I know what `CompareExchange` does, but I don't know why `CompareExchange` is needed. I mean why reading a value could result it being changed to 0?

Comment: So you don't know what it does, then. `CompareExchange` only writes to location if the value is equal to comparand. So it will only write 0 if it's already 0, and that means no actual change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary reason for use of`Interlocked.CompareExchange()` method it is to ensure reading 64-bit value is atomic on 32-bit systems. Reading 64-bit value on 64-bit system is atomic by default.

That is also why `Interlocked.Read()` method only accepts `Uint64` and `Int64` parameters.

`Interlocked.CompareExchange()` method is atomic operation that compares original value stored in `location1` with `comparand` parameter to make sure the value we want to exchange was not changed by other thread having access to that variable. If the value was not changed, then it is replaced, otherwise nothing happens, but always the original value stored in `location1` is returned.

So, the `Read()` method actually leveraging above written by trying to compare 0 with value stored in `location1` and based on that comparison either replaces the value or not, but returning the original value.

Which might be translated into something like

```cs
if(original == comparand) {
    return original;
} else {
    var temp = original;
    original = value;
    return temp;
}
```

That is why `Read()` method uses `CompareExchange()` method internally as anytime you use `CompareExchange()` you get original value and if you pass same values as `value` and `comparand` you never get into situation exchange actually happens. Either values are different and exchange is not going to happen at all or values are same and exchange is about to happen, but you are exchanging 0 for 0.

Comment: sorry still confused, isn't that `Interlocked.Read` is atomic, so the load operation won't be interrupted? also, Read is load operation, why there could be a store operation involved as `original = value;`?

Comment: `Interlocked.Read` is atomic operation, but `long temp = original;` or `ulong temp = original;` on 32-bit system is not. That is why `Interlocked.Read` was introduced only for 64-bit numeric types, but not any other as those are atomic on 32-bit and 64-bit by default.

Comment: Why there is store operation? I would say that it is just a workaround for a specific case of reading 64-bit value on 32-bit systems.

Comment: Why there is `original = value;`? It is how `Interlocked.CompareExchange` works.  The example of mine is just to explain the logic behind the decision to use it internally the way it is used.

Comment: .NET Framework 1.0 and 1.1 supported and most likely was designed only having in mind 32-bit systems. Next major version, .NET Framework 2.0, added full support for 64-bit systems. With that comes challenges that needs to be resolved. `Interlocked` class was introduced in version 1.1. `Interlocked.Read` was introduced in version 2.0 to tackle those challenges.

Comment: Does it make more sense or I made it even worse?